# Can we find a positive real sequence $(a_n)$ with $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^k=1/k$ for all positive integer $k$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Suppose that $a_1, a_2, a_3, \ldots$ are positive real numbers such that
\begin{align}
1/k=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^k \qquad \text{ for all integers } k>1.
\end{align}
What are $a_1, a_2, a_3, \ldots$?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We must have $0<a_n<1$ for all $n$. Also note  that for $k=2$, we must have for all $n$ the inequality $\displaystyle a_n^2\leq \frac{1}{2}$ hence $\displaystyle a_n\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. We have then for large $k$:
 $$1-a_n\geq 1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}>\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^{k^2}\geq a_n^{k^2}$$ and thus $1-a_n-a_n^{k^2}> 0$ for all $n$ and large $k$.

Now note that $\displaystyle \frac{1}{k}=\frac{1}{k+1}+\frac{1}{k(k+1)}$. Hence

$$\sum_{n\geq 1} a_n^k=\sum_{n\geq 1} a_n^{k+1}+\sum_{n\geq 1} a_n^{k(k+1)}$$
 We have hence for all (large) $k\geq 1$
 $$\sum_{n\geq 1}a_n^k(1-a_n-a_n^{k^2})=0$$
 and as $a_n^k(1-a_n-a_n^{k^2})>0$ for all $n$, we have a contradiction, no such sequence can exists.

Comment: awesome! Very nice solution!